# Digest Authentication Logging

Tags: marklogic

I am trying to troubleshoot a problem with digest authentication. Are there any trace events or log entries that an administrator should have access to for authentication events? I have the app server set to finest logging and don't see anything there. Any other ideas?

Update: I can see what it looks like in the access log when they make a request and it gives the user a 401 response code. The problem comes where sporadically, the user is prompted for a password again without closing their browser. Is there any way to know what is wrong with their request that the token is no longer valid?

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, please consider adding more information to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I finally realized that I could use `xdmp:get-request-header` in the rewriter for the app to capture the authorization header in the error log. This is the key information that I was hoping to gather. Now I can compare the authorization requests when the request works as expected to when the user is prompted to re-enter their credentials.

Comment: Correct, the authorization header is not included in logs for security reasons. Make sure to remove the logging when done with debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are access logs in the same directory as system and error logs. The filename will look like `9001_AccessLog.txt`, where the number is the port number. The directory for your OS's log files is listed here: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/logfiles#id_22670

Comment: Looking at the access logs, im not seeing any information or any detail about the log in attempt. Am I missing something? Is there just little or nothing logged?

Comment: @nobleb Typically it will show pretty granular details for every HTTP request made. Are sure the request is making it to ML?

Comment: Yes, I am sure the request comes in. There is nothing to indicate why there is a 401 being thrown when the user is already logged in. What is happening is that randomly a user is asked to re-authenticate even though they have been logged in and nothing has changed with their session. When I look at the log I see the 401 message, but no indication as to why. I am wondering if theres not a trace event or something that can be more informative. Thanks!

Comment: @nobleb Have you tested on another browser? HTTP auth caching is (I think always) handled by browsers, so if you have recently authenticated and you are browsing on the same port/server, your browser should resend credentials. It does not work like OAuth, where the server provides a cookie and determines when to log out a user.

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. It does not seem to be browser specific or environment specific.

Comment: @nobleb Does the 401 happen on every page? Just some pages? Always the same or on different pages? Can you reproduce it?